# Can I determine if a KeyEventArg is an letter or number?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, keyeventargs

Is there a way to determine if a key is letter/number (`A-Z`,`0-9`) in the `KeyEventArgs`? Or do I have to make it myself? I found a way with [e.KeyCode](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/598606-c-keyeventargs-how-quickly-determine-if-letter-number-presse), is that accurate?

```
if(((e.KeyCode >= Keys.A       && e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z )
 || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0      && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9 )
 || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9))
```

Comment: How do you define letter? only A-Z or letters in other languages too? And the same for numbers. And a key is not even a char(there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between keys and characters), so it can't be a letter/number.

Comment: You cannot know this from the KeyDown event.  Only after the virtual key is translated with the user's keyboard layout do you know.  Use the KeyPressed event instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [`char.IsLetterOrDigit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit.aspx) method on the [`KeyCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) of the event args:

```
bool isLetterOrDigit = char.IsLetterOrDigit((char) keyEventArgs.KeyCode);
```

Comment: This does not actually seem to work on azerty numbers. They require shift to be pressed to access them, and I fear that the shift + whatever the actual key is does not get processed right by the Char tools.

Comment: Does not work in vb.net. 'Keys' cannot be converted to 'Char' Weird

Answer (score 9):

[Char.IsNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isnumber.aspx) and [Char.IsLetter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx)

Comment: Lots of similar goodies in [`Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424s1h3z.aspx).

Comment: Ok, didn't know that one! nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

In WPF? Use PreviewTextInput or TextInput events instead of KeyDown

Answer (score 0):

[Char.IsLetter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx) accepts some of OEM key codes that was treated as alphabetical characters.

My case was when I typed a keyboard (tilde) then this Keycode was returned OEM3.

I inspected the value (**tilde**) and it says

> "192 'A'"

But actual typing '**A**' was

> "65 'A'"

As a result, both passed [Char.IsLetter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx) as True.

To avoid this, I put below code.

```
private bool IsAlphabetOrDigit(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var keyCode = (char)e.KeyCode;
    if ( false == char.IsNumber( keyCode ) &&  false == ((keyCode >= 'a' && keyCode <= 'z') || (keyCode >= 'A' && keyCode <= 'Z')))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```